# Git duplicate commits Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am new to git and I am trying to understand something.

1. Create and checkout a feature branch.
2. Make a change, commit and push.
3. Checkout on main branch, make a change, commit and push.
4. Checkout on feature branch, click on the main branch and rebase.(while feature branch is selected) -> Rebase feature onto main.
5. After solving the conflicts, in Git history of the feature branch I have: the commit from the main branch (added by rebase), the commit from feature branch.
6. At this point my feature branch shows an incoming commit and an outcoming commit.(in Intellij) -> I am trying to understand why this happens.

**Before rebase:**

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph feature main
* 1571a72 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) commit main branch
| * 4768d6b (origin/feature, feature) commit feature branch
|/
```

**After rebase:**

```
* 4674fe5 (HEAD -> feature) commit feature branch
* 1571a72 (origin/main, main) commit main branch
```

**After I update the feature branch again, with the incoming commit, from point 6.**

```
* f3f3735 (HEAD -> feature) commit feature branch
* 7a42764 commit main branch
* 4768d6b (origin/feature) commit feature branch
| * 1571a72 (origin/main, main) commit main branch
|/
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph featurebranch main`?

Comment: Maybe you forgot about step 6? When you tried to push your feature branch again, Git gave you an error that your branch had diverged, and suggested that you pull before pushing, so you mistakenly did what Git suggested and you pulled? That would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Now that you added a step 6, what did you do in that step? It looks like your statement "after I update the feature branch again" means you did a `git pull --rebase`. Like in my previous comment, you don't want to pull there. After rebasing onto main you simply need to force push your feature branch.

Comment: Note that `git rebase` fundamentally works by *copying* the original commits to the new, supposedly-improved, rebased commits. The original commits still exist, because no commit, once made, can ever be changed: it can be *forgotten* as long as you never look at its hash ID again, but if you've sent the originals off to some *other* Git repository, that other repository now thinks they're valuable gold that should be added back to the pile.

Answer (score 0):

First let's fix your problem:

```
# checkout branch feature
git switch feature

# Undo the last "update" you did in step 6
git reset --hard 4674fe5

# force push your branch to the remote feature branch
git push --force-with-lease origin feature
```

The lesson here is that anytime you rewrite your local branch, if you have already pushed it, you don't want to pull back in the old version of your branch again. When you pull, by default it will merge your old version back in, and that would give you a duplicate copy of your commit. If you use `pull --rebase` it will rebase your branch onto the old version of your branch, and that will leave you with the state you are seeing. The "Update" you did in step 6 pulled in your old copy of your branch. Instead of pulling, you want to blow away your old version of your branch and replace it with your new and improved version of your branch, and to do that you must force push.